# Unable to close CITRUS SPRING IOC container while exposing the test suite as a rest service

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, citrus-framework

I am using TESTNG to execute CITRUS test class while executing with the following citrus code was executing properly and it was closing spring container at the end.

```
TestNG testng = new TestNG();
    List<String> suites = Lists.newArrayList();
    suites.add("C:/Users/mounika/citrusrest/CitrusDemoServices/src/test/java/com/citrus/samples/TestSuit.xml");//path to testng xml..
    testng.setTestSuites(suites);
    testng.run();
```

the test class was executing fine but while exposing the above code  as rest service the citrus spring container was not closing. Generally while running  normally with out exposing to rest service at the end I am getting the following log

```
 18:26:08.459 [Thread-0] INFO 
org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext - Closing 
org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext@6b1274d2: 
startup date [Mon Nov 27 18:26:02 IST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
18:26:08.459 [Thread-0] DEBUG 
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - 
Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'lifecycleProcessor'
18:26:08.459 [Thread-0] DEBUG 
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - 
Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.
DefaultListableBeanFactory@25d250c6: defining beans 
[org.springframework.context.annotation.
internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.
annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.
context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.
springframework.
context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,
org.springframework.context.event.internalEventListenerProcessor,
org.springframework.context.event.internalEventListenerFactory,
citrusSpringConfig,com.consol.citrus.functions.FunctionConfig,
functionRegistry,citrusFunctionLibrary,
com.consol.citrus.validation.matcher.ValidationMatcherConfig,
validationMatcherRegistry,xmlValidationMatcher,
citrusValidationMatcherLibrary,
com.consol.citrus.validation.MessageValidatorConfig,
defaultXmlMessageValidator,defaultMessageHeaderValidator,
defaultXpathMessageValidator,defaultJsonMessageValidator,
defaultJsonPathMessageValidator,defaultPlaintextMessageValidator,
defaultBinaryBase64MessageValidator,defaultGzipBinaryBase64MessageValidator,
defaultXhtmlMessageValidator,defaultXhtmlXpathMessageValidator,
defaultGroovyXmlMessageValidator,defaultGroovyJsonMessageValidator,
defaultGroovyTextMessageValidator,citrusMessageValidatorRegistry,
testContextFactory,endpointFactory,referenceResolver,
messageConstructionInterceptors,loggingReporter,htmlReporter,
testListeners,testActionListeners,testSuiteListeners,messageListeners,
failureStackTestListener]; root of factory hierarchy
```

But while calling as a rest service it was not showing the above log at the end due to this after the first Rest hit, In the second rest hit also citrus was executing the same xml test cases. I want to change the testcase xml names for every Rest hit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If not explicitly shut down manually the Spring application context used in Citrus is bound to the JVM shutdown. If your JVM runtime terminates the Spring application context will shutdown automatically.

If you are running that TestNG process as part of the server JVM the termination is not done as long as the server is running. So I see two options for you:

1. Run the tests in a separate JVM process using the Java
   `java.lang.ProcessBuilder` API.
2. Add some logic to the after suite TestNG phase that performs a
   graceful shutdown of the Spring application context manually.

Comment: I am using   extends TestRunnerAfterSuiteSupport and I am closing spring application context by using code  {  @Autowired
  ConfigurableApplicationContext  senv ;   and inside the afterSuite method  i am using  (senv.close())  } to stop container it was working fine with first hit but with the second hit I am getting the following error { java.lang.IllegalStateException: The ApplicationContext loaded for [[MergedContextConfiguration@56383ed5 testClass = GenricTest, locations = '{}'} some extra error I am getting